# create_thread_cb, unable to create thread

Tags: c#, android, gps

this is my first question here, and I hope I don't do anything wrong.

Currently I am working on a device bringup for Cyanogenmod, but I can't seem to get gps working, because of the problem mentioned in the titel.

In the gps driver, there's this code:

```
state->thread = callback_backup.create_thread_cb(gps_native_thread, gps_state_thread, state);
```

which is producing this error:
D/gps_mtk (  598): could not create gps thread: [Try again]

a full log of the boot process can be found here:
https://paste.ee/p/UsYy4

gps_state_thread function is this:

```
void
gps_state_thread(void *arg)
{
    static float count = 0;
    GpsState*   state = (GpsState*) arg;
    state->test_time += 1;
//  state->thread_exit_flag=0;
    NmeaReader  reader[1];
#if NEED_IPC_WITH_CODEC 
    char buf_for_codec[2048];
#endif
    int         gps_fd     = state->fd;
    int         control_fd = state->control[1];

    int epoll_fd = state->epoll_hd;
    int         test_started = 0;

    nmea_reader_init( reader );

    int mnld_fd = bind_udp_socket(MTK_MNLD2HAL);
    DBG("WARNING: mnld_fd=%d\n", mnld_fd);
    if(mnld_fd >= 0) {
        if(epoll_register( epoll_fd, mnld_fd ) < 0)
            ERR("ERR: epoll register control_fd error, error num is %d\n, message is %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        else
            DBG("WARNING: epoll_register successfully\n");
    }

#if NEED_IPC_WITH_CODEC
    int sock_codec, size_codec;
    struct sockaddr_un un;
    socklen_t client_addr_len;
    memset(&un, 0, sizeof(un));
    un.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(un.sun_path, EVDO_CODEC_SOC);
    if ((state->sock_codec = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {   
        ERR("create socket for communicate with codec error, message %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }   
    unlink(EVDO_CODEC_SOC);
    size_codec = sizeof(un.sun_family)+strlen(un.sun_path);
    if(bind(state->sock_codec, (struct sockaddr *)&un, size_codec) < 0)
    {
        ERR("bind fail, message = %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }
    if(listen(state->sock_codec, 5) == -1)
    {
        ERR("listern error, message is %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return; 
    }
    DBG("listen done\n");   
    int a = chmod(EVDO_CODEC_SOC, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IXUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IXGRP);
    DBG("chmod res = %d\n", a); //770<--mode

    if(chown(EVDO_CODEC_SOC, -1, AID_INET))
    {
        ERR("chown error: %s", strerror(errno));
    }

    epoll_register(epoll_fd, state->sock_codec);
#endif
    // register control file descriptors for polling
    if(epoll_register( epoll_fd, control_fd ) < 0)
        ERR("epoll register control_fd error, error num is %d\n, message is %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    if(epoll_register( epoll_fd, gps_fd) < 0)
        ERR("epoll register gps_fd error, error num is %d\n, message is %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));

    DBG("gps thread running: PPID[%d], PID[%d]\n", getppid(), getpid());
    release_condition(&lock_for_sync[M_INIT]);
    DBG("HAL thread is ready, realease lock, and CMD_START can be handled\n");
#if SEM
    sem_t *sem;
    sem = sem_open("/data/misc/read_dev_gps", O_CREAT, S_IRWXU|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH,1);
    if(sem == SEM_FAILED)
    {           
        ERR("init semaphore FAIL, error message is %s \n", strerror(errno));
        return ;
    }
    else
        DBG("create semaphore ok\n");
#endif
    // now loop
    for (;;) {
#if NEED_IPC_WITH_CODEC
        struct epoll_event   events[3];
#else
        struct epoll_event   events[4];
#endif
        int                  ne, nevents;
#if NEED_IPC_WITH_CODEC
        nevents = epoll_wait( epoll_fd, events, 3, -1 );
#else
        nevents = epoll_wait( epoll_fd, events, 4, -1 );
#endif
        if (nevents < 0) {
            if (errno != EINTR)
                ERR("epoll_wait() unexpected error: %s", strerror(errno));
            continue;
        }
        VER("gps thread received %d events", nevents);
        for (ne = 0; ne < nevents; ne++) {
            if ((events[ne].events & (EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP)) != 0) {
                ERR("EPOLLERR or EPOLLHUP after epoll_wait() !?");
                goto Exit;
            }
            if ((events[ne].events & EPOLLIN) != 0) {
                int  fd = events[ne].data.fd;

                if (fd == control_fd)
                {
                    char  cmd = 255;
                    int   ret;
                    DBG("gps control fd event");
                    do {
                        ret = read( fd, &cmd, 1 );
                    } while (ret < 0 && errno == EINTR);

                    if (cmd == CMD_QUIT) {
                        DBG("gps thread quitting on demand");
                        goto Exit;
                    }
                    else if (cmd == CMD_START) {
                        if (!started) {
                            DBG("gps thread starting  location_cb=%p", &callback_backup);
                            started = 1;
                            nmea_reader_set_callback( reader, &state->callbacks);
                        }
                    }
                    #ifdef GPS_AT_COMMAND
                    else if (cmd == CMD_TEST_START) {                        
                        if ((!test_started)&&(1 == test_mode_flag)) {
                           // DBG("**AT Command test_start: test_cb=%p", state->callbacks.test_cb);
                            test_started = 1;
                            nmea_reader_set_callback(reader, &state->callbacks);
                        }                        
                    }
                    else if (cmd == CMD_TEST_STOP) {                        
                        if(test_started) {
                            DBG("**AT Command test_stop");
                            test_started = 0;
                            nmea_reader_set_callback(reader, NULL);
                        }                       
                    }
                    else if (cmd == CMD_TEST_SMS_NO_RESULT) {
                        DBG("**CMD_TEST_SMS_NO_RESULT, update result!!");
                        sms_airtest_no_signal_report(Err_Code,0,0,0,0);
                        //nmea_reader_update_at_test_result(reader, Err_Code, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
                    }
                    #endif
#if EPO_SUPPORT
                    else if (cmd == CMD_DOWNLOAD){
                        DBG("Send download request in HAL.");
                        mGpsXtraCallbacks.download_request_cb();
                    }
#endif
                    else if (cmd == CMD_STOP) {
                        if (started) {
                            DBG("gps thread stopping");
                            started = 0;
                            nmea_reader_set_callback( reader, NULL );
                            DBG("CMD_STOP has been receiving from HAL thread, release lock so can handle CLEAN_UP\n");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (cmd == CMD_RESTART) {
                        reader->fix_mode = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if (fd == gps_fd)
                {
                    if(!flag_unlock)
                    {
                        release_condition(&lock_for_sync[M_START]);
                        flag_unlock = 1;                            
                        DBG("got first NMEA sentence, release lock to set state ENGINE ON, SESSION BEGIN");
                    }
                    VER("gps fd event");
                    if(report_time_interval > ++count){
                        DBG("[trace]count is %f\n", count);
                        int ret = read( fd, buff, sizeof(buff) );
                        continue;
                    }
                    count = 0;
                    for (;;) {
                        int  nn, ret;
#if SEM
                        if(sem_wait(sem) != 0)
                        {
                            ERR("sem wait error, message is %s \n", strerror(errno));
                            close(fd);
                            return ;
                        }
                        else
                            DBG("get semaphore, can read now\n");
#endif
                        ret = read( fd, buff, sizeof(buff) );
#if NEED_IPC_WITH_CODEC
                        memset(buf_for_codec, 0, sizeof(buf_for_codec));
                        memcpy(buf_for_codec, buff, sizeof(buff));
#endif
#if SEM
                        if(sem_post(sem) != 0)
                        {
                            ERR("sem post error, message is %s\n", strerror(errno));
                            close(fd);
                            return ;
                        }
                        else
                            DBG("post semaphore, read done\n");
#endif
                        if (ret < 0) {
                            if (errno == EINTR)
                                continue;
                            if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
                                ERR("error while reading from gps daemon socket: %s: %p", strerror(errno), buff);
                            break;
                        }
                        DBG("received %d bytes:\n", ret);
                        gps_nmea_end_tag = 0;
                        for (nn = 0; nn < ret; nn++)
                        {
                            if(nn == (ret-1))
                                gps_nmea_end_tag = 1;

                            nmea_reader_addc( reader, buff[nn] );
                        }
                    }
                    VER("gps fd event end");
                }
                else if(fd == mnld_fd) {
                    mnld_to_gps_handler(mnld_fd,state);
                }
#if NEED_IPC_WITH_CODEC
                else if(fd == state->sock_codec)
                {
                    client_addr_len = sizeof(un);
                    int accept_ret = accept(state->sock_codec, (struct sockaddr*)&un, &client_addr_len);
                    if(accept_ret == -1)
                    {   
                        ERR("accept error, message is %s\n", strerror(errno));
                        continue;
                    }   
                    DBG("accept done\n");
                    int cmd, write_len;
                    GpsLocation tLocation;

                    if(recv(accept_ret, &cmd, sizeof(cmd),0)<0)
                    {
                        ERR("read from codec error, message = %s\n", strerror(errno));
                        close(accept_ret);
                        continue;
                    }
                    DBG("read done, cmd: %d\n", cmd);
                    switch(cmd)
                    {
                    case 1://need NMEA sentences
                        write_len = send(accept_ret, buf_for_codec, sizeof(buff),0);
                        DBG("write %d bytes to codec\n", write_len);
                        break;
                    case 2: //For AGPS location froward
                        DBG("Snd to UI");
                        char ack_buf[10] = {0};
                        strcpy(ack_buf, "cmd2_ack");
                        write_len = send(accept_ret, ack_buf, sizeof(ack_buf), 0);
                        DBG("wait rcv location data");
                        if(recv(accept_ret, &tLocation, sizeof(tLocation), 0) < 0)
                        {
                            ERR("read from codec error, message = %s\n", strerror(errno));      
                        }else{
                            if(callback_backup.location_cb){
                                DBG("Update location data to UI");
                                callback_backup.location_cb(&tLocation);
                            }else{
                                DBG("Location CB is null");
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        ERR("unknonwn codec message, codec send %d to me\n", cmd);
                        break;  
                    }
                    close(accept_ret);
                }
#endif
                else
                {
                    ERR("epoll_wait() returned unkown fd %d ?", fd);
                }
            }
        }
    }
Exit:
    DBG("HAL thread is exiting, release lock to clean resources\n");
    close(mnld_fd);
    release_condition(&lock_for_sync[M_CLEANUP]);
    return;
}
```

Please let me know, if you need to know anything else.

Comment: I have solved the issue now. Wasn't really related to the part of code I suspected...I had to patch framework according to my stock rom source.